# Bind the value of a service to a controller so it updates if the service updates

Tags: angularjs

There are a lot of references that discuss this, but I just need someone to confirm if this is right or not.  If i have a service which I want to share information with a controller, and the controller should update on changes to the service I need to return an object from the service, like:

```
.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var data = {};

    var service = {
        constant: 1234,
        getData: function() {
            return data;
        },
        doCalculation: function() {
            service.constant = data.const*25;
        },
        requestData: function() {
            return $http.get('/blah')
                       .then(function( response ) {
                           data = response.data;
                       }
        }
    }

    return service;
}])
```

Now to pass it to a controller for use and have it update if requestData is invoked again during maybe a route resolve() I would and can't do:

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['myService', function(myService) {

    var self = this;

    // PART 1
    self.data = myService.constant;  // this is not bound and will not update, yes? 
    self.data1 = myService.getData(); // this is not bound and will not update, yes?
    // So, the above would be assigned or invoked only once on init of controller and 
    // would have to reset manually by assigning either a value or the result of the 
    // the function call again

    self.myService = myService; // pass entire service
    // Now, in controller functions or in the UI I can invoke the functions or access
    // values, and those results will be bound and update on changes to the service
    // since I've passed it in its entirety

    self.getData = function() {
        return self.myService.getData();
    }

    // PART 2
    self.getData = myService.getData; // would you ever do this?
    // You wouldn't have to pass the entire service if it had a bunch of different
    // parts that maybe you didn't want to be available...

}]);

PART 1
<div ng-show="myCtrl.myService.doCalculation() === someNumber">You can't see me unless doCalculation resolves to someNumber</div>

PART 2
<div ng-show="myCtrl.getData() === anotherNumber">Would this work? and would you want to do this?</div>
```

I just can't seem to get the concept of how sharing data between a service(s) and a controller(s) works, and when it is working and when it won't.  If all you can do is say correct, wrong, wrong, oh man so wrong, that's kewl, but if you can also say and this is why, I'd be ecstatic to put this away as finally resolved so I don't keep questioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go too far here..

A `controller` is your view's **helper**. You need to generate vars and functions on your scope to help your view accomplish things.

Your business model however, is something that you would like to have **one** reference.

What I do is create my business model on a `service`, so **multiple entities can share it**(e.g. other services, directives, controllers etc.).

When my `controller` kicks in, I add a pointer to the model from the `service` and use the same reference between them. I bind the models properties to the view.

So:

1. A `controller` has it's own methods(dont share the `service's` methods). A `controllers` method should be short and use a `service` method as a helper.
2. A `controller` should have a reference to the business model which is created by a `service`. All your `ajax` calls should come from the service and populate\send the model that the `service` is holding.
3. A `controller` should have basic view functions(e.g. decide which css class to apply to an element). When you submit a form, the `controller` function should call the `service's` submit which will perform you ajax call.

Example:

Html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Model.propA" />
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="Model.propB" />
        <div ng-show="ShouldShowSecondDiv()">Second Div.</div>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="SubmitForm()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    // simple controller "view method".
    $scope.ShouldShowSecondDiv = function () {
        return $scope.Model.propB > 12;
    };

    // "complex" "non-view method" -> use service.
    $scope.SubmitForm = function () {
        myService.SubmitModelToServer();
    };

    // get the ref. from the service.
    $scope.Model = myService.GetModel();
});

app.service('myService', function () {
    this.Model = {};

    // perform an ajax to get the model or whatever.
    this.GetModel = function () {
        this.Model = {
            propA: 'Im prop A',
            propB: 12
        };

        return this.Model;
    };

    // submit it to the server via $http. Check the log and you will see the binding(if you changed a value in the view).
    this.SubmitModelToServer = function () {
        console.log("ajax or whatever....submitted");
        console.log(this.Model);
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qfv9umr7/).

Comment: Okay, so in the case of the last line $scope.Model = myService.GetModel(); if the user triggers a route and it resolves a successful promise that updates the view and myService.GetModel(), an action invoked in a different controller, will the controller you have above have its $scope.Model updated automatically since the value of $scope.Model is linked to myService.GetModel(), or is the value of $scope.Model set when the view is loaded and not reset until the view is destroyed and reloaded? I can see what you're doing above by wrapping the myService submit in a locally scoped function.

Comment: Before everything occurs the controller and the service both point to the same "Model". Now if for some reason the model's reference is changed in the service and not in the controller you will loose your "controller-service" model binding. There are two options here:
1. Your controller "starts" the proccess and calls a service method which brings a new model. The controller will have a callback and "re-bind" it's model. For a more complex solution(e.g. some third party component uses the service to update the model, you will need NOT to assign a new model(not do this.Model = newModel)

Comment: But perform a copy(e.g. this.Model.ObjA = newModel.ObjA on all props). I once encountered "lost reference problems" and that was my solution. I'm pretty sure there is a third party method that will do this for you.

Comment: Sorry Amir, I really feel thick.  If I have this.Model in a service and in a controller I have this.value = MyService.GetModel(), and then a http request changes just the value(s) of this.Model it won't be updated in the controller's view, right?  Since it only gets set when the application is initially digested. But, if I wrap a controller function and call a service method within it I will get the most up to date value of this.Model with any changes since I at that time invoked a function that directly calls out to myService.GetModel() at the moment I need it.

Comment: If your service does $http.get(url).then(function(res){this.Model = res}), you service is changing the reference to this.Model. In that case, your controller is pointing to the “previous” Model and you don’t have the service-controller binding (your controllers binding get detached). You will need to do this yourself. A way to do this is to return a promise from the service and add a callback in your contoller(your controller will do something like this: service.UpdateModel().then(function(res){$scope.Model = res}) and update the reference as well.